# How can I log text in other language like Japanese using slf4j

Tags: java, encoding, kibana, slf4j, utf

I want to log text written in Japanese language and show it in Kibana.
In console I am seeing the logs are coming in Japanese language, but in Kibana the logs are coming like  ??????? instead of Japanese text. 
Can someone tell how to write the logs to get this in Japanese language in Kibana as well?

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to check if Kibana supports japanese localization. It really does, however you have to modify something in the configuration file as quoted below (with emphasis of mine)

> Kibana now supports Japanese, in addition to Simplified Chinese and English. If you’d like **to use Kibana with Japanese, set i18n.locale to ja-JP in your kibana.yml file**.  The Japanese localization is a work in progress. ([source](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-7-2-0-released#kij))

Did you have modified the `kibana.yml` file already?

Comment: This japanese support is in version 7.2 and my kibana is 6.6, so I guess this is not supported there.